# Downgrade jQuery version from 2.1.1 to 1.9.1 via Package Console Manager from Visual Studio

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, nuget-package, package-managers

I have jQuery version 2.1.1 and wanted to downgrade to 1.9.1, i have tried Install and Update commands, but both are failing claiming that a more recent version of jquery is installed for my project:

```
PM> Update-Package jQuery -Version 1.9.1
PM> Install-Package jQuery -Version 1.9.1
```

I thought that package manager would be taking care of this process but it seems not. I cannot uninstall it because of dependencies of others installed packages.

What are my options?

Comment: Edit the `packages.config` file in your project.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, Should I delete the entry package id = "jQuery"?

Comment: Just point out the version you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the jQuery entry in your packages.config file, then just run the install for the specific version.

e.g.

```
PM> Install-Package jQuery -Version 1.9.1
```

You can then simply delete the old JQuery version (only one script file).

*PS: I recommend you go with jQuery 1.11.0 if you can :)*

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered a similar case where I wanted to downgrade version of jquery which was in turn acting as dependency for various other components.

The easiest way I found was that go to *Nuget Package Manager > Manage Nuget Packages for Solution*

[image: Downgrade]
Select relevant package (jquery for me) under *Installed* tab on left hand side of screen. On right hand side, You will be seeing a dropdown next to *Version* label. Select the version to which you want to downgrade (or upgrade) & Click on Install.

**PS: This is available for VS2015+**